# How to disable or hide a structure group?

Tags: tridion

I would like to disable or hide a structure group that I am creating using the API.
How can I do that? I don't see any relevant methods or properties in the API.

Answer (score 3):

You best option is to set security (remove all permissions) on it so that nobody (except for admins) will see it. Your only other option is to set is "Publishable" property to false, but it will still be visible.

You might however get more answers at https://tridion.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Chris. I can export the securities and permissions as well when i move to SIT right?

Comment: System Intgration Testing environment. DTAP

Comment: How are you moving your structure groups through DTAP? Content Porter or some other mechanism

Comment: I will use Content Porter only to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately (for you), CP does not move security settings (because it is rare that anyone has the same domains/users in each environment) - Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504396/what-is-best-way-to-export-and-import-security-permissions-across-environments for more ideas on moving permissions etc. Alternatively explain your challenge further and we may be able to support you with more ideas. Please post on http://tridion.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be accomplished using Data Extenders in Tridion CME GUI Extensions. This is where I would start investigating...